# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while running OCUnit tests in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, ocunit, ocmockito

I got stuck with issue. I have OCUnit tests. I can run them successfully in iOS 7 simulator but I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iOS 6 simulator.

Here is screenshot form Xcode:
[image]

I'm using `OCMockito` and `OCHamcrest`.

Do you have any idea what was the cause? I'm trying to investigate and find out the cause.

Update:

Here code for test case (at least from log):

```
static NSString *const EMAIL = @"foo@example.com";
static NSString *const PASSWORD = @"secret";

@interface MDLoginViewControllerTest : SenTestCase

@end

@implementation MDLoginViewControllerTest {
    MDLoginViewController *controller;
    MDLoginView *loginView;
    UIWindow *window;

    MDAlertManager *mockedAlertManager;
    MDNetwork *mockedNetwork;
    MDStorage *mockedStorage;
}

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

    mockedAlertManager = mock([MDAlertManager class]);
    mockedNetwork = mock([MDNetwork class]);
    mockedStorage = mock([MDStorage class]);

    controller = [[MDLoginViewController alloc] initWithAlert:mockedAlertManager andNetwork:mockedNetwork andStorage:mockedStorage];

    window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
    [window addSubview:controller.view];
}

# pragma mark - Test Helpers

- (void)login
{
    [controller requestDiscoveryWithEmail:EMAIL andPassword:PASSWORD];
}

- (void)mockLoginView
{
    loginView = mock([MDLoginView class]);
    controller.loginView = loginView;
}

- (void (^)(NSError *))runControllerForgotPasswordForEmailAndReturnBlock
{
    [controller recoverAccountPasswordForEmail:EMAIL];

    MKTArgumentCaptor *captor = [MKTArgumentCaptor new];
    [verify(mockedNetwork) forgotPasswordForEmail:EMAIL andCallback:[captor capture]];

    void (^callback)(NSError *) = [captor value];
    return callback;
}

# pragma mark - Tests itself

- (void)testAlertThatInputIsEmptyWhenLoginIsNil
{
    [controller requestDiscoveryWithEmail:nil andPassword:@"pass"];

    [verify(mockedAlertManager) showAlertMessage:EMPTY_DATA_MESSAGE    withTitle:WRONG_DATA_TITLE];
    [verifyCount(mockedNetwork, never()) discoveryWithEmail:anything() andPassword:anything() andCallback:anything()];
}

- (void)testAlertThatInputIsEmptyWhenLoginIsWhitespacesOnly
{
    [controller requestDiscoveryWithEmail:@"  " andPassword:@"pass"];

    [verify(mockedAlertManager) showAlertMessage:EMPTY_DATA_MESSAGE withTitle:WRONG_DATA_TITLE];
    [verifyCount(mockedNetwork, never()) discoveryWithEmail:anything() andPassword:anything() andCallback:anything()];
}

- (void)testAlertThatInputIsEmptyWhenPasswordIsNil
{
    [controller requestDiscoveryWithEmail:@"test@t.com" andPassword:nil];

    [verify(mockedAlertManager) showAlertMessage:EMPTY_DATA_MESSAGE withTitle:WRONG_DATA_TITLE];
    [verifyCount(mockedNetwork, never()) discoveryWithEmail:anything() andPassword:anything() andCallback:anything()];
}

- (void)testAlertThatInputIsEmptyWhenPasswordIsWhitespacesOnly
{
    [controller requestDiscoveryWithEmail:@"test@ts.com" andPassword:@"   "];

    [verify(mockedAlertManager) showAlertMessage:EMPTY_DATA_MESSAGE withTitle:WRONG_DATA_TITLE];
    [verifyCount(mockedNetwork, never()) discoveryWithEmail:anything() andPassword:anything() andCallback:anything()];
}

- (void)testAlertThatWrongEmailWhenEmailIsInvalid
{
    [controller requestDiscoveryWithEmail:@"test" andPassword:@"passs"];

    [verify(mockedAlertManager) showAlertMessage:ENTER_VALID_EMAIL_MESSAGE withTitle:WRONG_DATA_TITLE];
    [verifyCount(mockedNetwork, never()) discoveryWithEmail:anything() andPassword:anything() andCallback:anything()];
}

- (void)testCallNetworkIfInputIsValid
{
    [self login];

    [verify(mockedNetwork) discoveryWithEmail:EMAIL andPassword:PASSWORD andCallback:anything()];
}
}
```

More images from Xcode:
[image]
[image]

Update:
Looks like issue is in method that is calling method from mock and one of argument is block which has strong reference on `self`.

Here is code for this method:

```
- (void)requestDiscoveryWithEmail:(NSString *)email andPassword:(NSString *)password
{
    ...
    // store email / password on view
    _email = [email copy];
    _password = [password copy];

    [self.loginView showSpinner];

    [self.network discoveryWithEmail:email
        andPassword:password
        andCallback:^(NSDictionary *response, NSError *error) {
        // Hide the spinner
        [self.loginView hideSpinner];

        if (error) {
            [self showError:error];
        }
        else {
            if (![self isResponseComplete:response]) {
                _response = [response copy];
                [self.alertManager showAlertMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"We were unable to reach some services because maintenance or some issues", @"Unreachable services message")
                                      withTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Issues happened", @" Issues happened title")
                                    andDelegate:self];
            }
            else {
               [self processDiscoveryResponse:response];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: can't you narrow down the error to a method?

Comment: Can you teach me how to do that?

Comment: Try and run the tests individually and see which one is causing the crash

Comment: Great advice! It looks issue appears when I try to call an object on instance of mock. Investigating!